# Using jquery to enable div on a page based on a radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to enable a div if yes or no was selected from a radio button using jquery. The default is no div shows up
when the page loads. When you now select a radio button it determines which div shows up.

Here is what the html code will look like

```
        <html>
        <head>Testing</head>
        <body>
        <p>Are you 70 years and older?  <input type="radio" value="yes" name="myradiobutton" /> Yes <input type="radio" value="no" name="myradiobutton" /> No</p>

        <div style="display: none" id="yes">
            <p>Yes was selected</p>
        </div>

        <div style="display: none" id="no">
            <p>No was selected</p>
        </div>

        </body>
        </html>
```

It is a long time I did jquery but was wondering how I can turn this on and off with jquery below.
How can I write this such that I will be able to control the styles on each div via jquery(turning it on and off based on the radio button selection)?

```
        $(".myradiobutton").click(function(){
            var selectedval = $("#myradiobutton input[type='radio']:checked").val();
            if(selectedval == "yes"){
                //show the yes div
            }
            if(selectedval == "no"){
                //show the no div
            }
        });
```

Comment: And where is `#myradiobutton` element??

Comment: #myradiobutton is the name of the radio button group. I might be wrong using this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id must be unique .. You've to use it for only one element .. You can use same class for `divs` so you can hide both of them in one selection .. Also you can use the code like this instead of going with if statement .. And I prefer to use `change` event instead of `click` for radio,checkbox,select

```js
$("[name='myradiobutton']").on('change' , function(){
    var selectedval = $("input[type='radio'][name='myradiobutton']:checked").val();
    $('.just_test').hide(0).filter('#'+selectedval).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Are you 70 years and older?  <input type="radio" value="yes" name="myradiobutton" /> Yes <input type="radio" value="no" name="myradiobutton" /> No</p>

<div style="display: none" class="just_test" id="yes">
    <p>Yes was selected</p>
</div>

<div style="display: none" class="just_test" id="no">
    <p>No was selected</p>
</div>
```

Don't forget to add `class="just_test"` to the `divs` in html

Answer (score 0):

You tried to use `#myradiobutton` as a query selector but the `#` represents the `id` attribute of an element which you don't have in your HTML code.

To fix it, you can't have your two `<input type="radio">` elements both using the `myradiobutton` as `id`.

Instead of that, my suggestion is to use `<label>` to represent the `<input>`s.

> Example below:

```
<input type="radio" name="age" value="yes" id="older-than-70">
<label for="older-than-70">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="age" value="no" id="younger-than-70">
<label for="younger-than-70">No</label>
```

- `<input>` element uses attribute `id` to identify itself and uses attribute `name="age"` to group with other `<input>`s.
- `<label>` element uses attribute `for` as a pointer to hook to the `<input>` with matching `id`.